# What is $^{y(slog_xa)}x$?

Tags: tetration

What is $^{y(slog_xa)}x$ ?

In [this website about tetration](https://andydude.github.io/tetration/archives/tetration2/mthds.html), it's shown that $^{y+slog_xa}x=$ $^{y}x^a$, as $^{1+slog_xa}x=x^a$.

[image]

So what is $^{y(slog_xa)}x$ ? Is it $^{y}a$ ?

Comment: Can you actually compute it for a few sample values of $x,y,s$?